How to update the checkbox field value in Sitecore Powershell Extensions?
I'm using the PowerShell script to update a specific field of the item in the content tree. It works for singleline, richtext, link fields but the update is not applied to the checkbox field. How to update the checkbox field by reading a value from the CSV file.
I am trying to read as below
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField]$checkboxField = $item.Fields["IsChecked"]
$checkboxField.Checked = $row.IsChecked


When you read checkbox Field from CSV file. You need to convert it to Boolean first then you can assign/update the checkbox field value using powershell. I'm assuming in your excel file IsChecked column value in True or Falase.
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Home/YourItemName"
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
if ($row.IsChecked -as [bool]) {
        [Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField]$checkboxField = $item.Fields["IsChecked"]
        $checkboxField.Checked = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($row.IsChecked)
    }
$item.Editing.EndEdit()

Hope this helps!!

Thank you for your detailed response! Your solution perfectly addresses the issue I was facing

You could use this code to update value of checkbox. Here is a sample code.
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Home/Sample"
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["IsSelect"].Value = "1"
$item.Editing.EndEdit()

If you see the raw value of the checkbox field it saves 1 as true like this.

Hope this helps.

Inside Powershell, $true/$false are the boolean values that need to be assigned to set/unset checkbox field value in the above script. Therefore the value of $row.IsChecked in your case, must be translated to boolean values with the help of [System.Convert]::ToBooleanfunction, to set checkbox field value.
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{BF0B22DE-528C-40B6-A839-3CD3B240F649}"

$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField]$checkboxField = $item.Fields["IsProduct"]
$checkboxField.Checked = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($row.IsChecked)
$item.Editing.EndEdit()

Note: The value of $row.IsChecked must be set as either True/False inside the excel file.
You can also use following snippet to set the value of the checkbox field, with the help of 1/0 value.
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{BF0B22DE-528C-40B6-A839-3CD3B240F649}"
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["IsProduct"].Value = 1 or 0
$item.Editing.EndEdit()

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have doubts.
